# get information from/about ODBC DSN

Tags: odbc

Is there anyway to get information out of an Odbc data source when you know the DSN name?

example, get a user id, etc

I need to open a connection to some dataSource and execute some command. The only thing I know is the data source name (defined in the ODBC Data Source Administrator) and the command text.

Now, if I need some more info about that data source, is there anyway to get that info programmatically? Maybe a class that represents an ODBC data source?

tks

Comment: Do you really mean DNS - or DSN? Please expand your question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I agree w/ Mr. Butterworth's comment, in that I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can find some of the information in the registry in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\{DSN Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole [C API to support ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714562%28VS.85%29.aspx). Other languages (and you don't say which one(s) you are using) provide wrappers around this. Given only a data source name, you *may* be able to access the data it refers to - it depends how it's been set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`SQLGetPrivateProfileString` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from `odbccp32.dll` to retrieve the information that you're looking for.

Importing the DLL and function looks like this in C#:

```
    [DllImport("odbccp32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW(string lpszSection, string lpszEntry, string lpszDefault, char[] RetBuffer, int cbRetBuffer, string lpszFilename);
```

It looks like this in VB.NET:

```
    <DllImport("odbccp32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Function SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW(lpszSection As String, lpszEntry As String, RetBuffer As Char(), cbRetBuffer As Integer, lpszFilename As String) As Integer
```